# Excel VBA Formulas to populate until last row , not working for VERY LAST row

Tags: excel, vba, calculation

I have the following formulas calculating for a worksheet in my workbook.  For some reason, the very last row is not populating the formulas.

ANy idea what's off here?  It works perfectly EXCEPT for the very last row for all 3 of these formulas and I'm not sure why.

```
Sub CLFormulas()
    
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CurrentList")
    
            .Cells(1, 18).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CurrentList!Q1,AF!A:A,1,FALSE),0)"
            End With
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CurrentList")
    
            .Cells(1, 19).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1).Formula = "=IF(AND(R1 = 0, L1 = ""Override""),""Yes"",""No"")"
            End With
            
                 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CurrentList")
    
            .Cells(1, 20).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(C1,F1,K1)"
            End With
    
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you subtracting 1? Why are you finding the last row three times, instead of finding it once?

Comment: Why the repeated `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CurrentList")` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have - 1 so it will never do the bottom row

Comment: You guys are right .. simply eliminating the -1 fixed the issue SMH lol..  For the finding the rows 3 times, I'm going to need to a do a bit of research to see how to structure the syntax, but I also did not even think about that.  Great call out!